# Vue.js declarative rendering between pre tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am just getting started with Vue.js, trying to create a function where i want a user to be able to customize a form.

So what I'm doing is i have a preview of the form, here a user can change for example the label for a input element.

Under this form i have the code for the form between `<pre></pre>` tags, so that the user can copy the form he has customized and paste it somewhere else.

Now to the problem. Using declarative rendering is working just fine, until i want to use it where the code is (that is, between the `<pre>` tags). Of course instead of for example rendering the name for a label, the code is presented instead.

```
<label>{{ label 1 }}</label>
```

This is rendered fine.

```
<pre><label>{{ label 1 }}</label></pre>
```

And this renders the code instead.

JS-code

```
const v = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        name: 'Namn',
        mail: 'Mejl',
        message: 'Meddelande'
    }
})
```

So my question is, can this be circumvented in any way?

Comment: You want html to be rendered between the pre-tags?

Comment: Well, what I really want to do is show a bunch of HTML-code, but not render it. For this the pre-tags are working fine. However I also want to be able to update this code, but since it is between the pre-tags I can't.

Prehaps there is a better way to be doing this?

Comment: Um.. Can't understand your question. can you provide screenshots of what you expected and what you are seeing now

Comment: If you could provide a small fiddle for what is happening and what you want to happen?

Comment: Sure thing! Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/kRscO3i.png so if you look at the form where it says "Namn", this string is rendered by using {{ name }}. Then take a look under "Kod" here you kan see that {{ name }} is not rendered, instead the code is shown. What I want to do is show the string "Name" here as well, since I want users to be able to copy the code and use elsewhere.

Does that make things any clearer? :)

Comment: The pre tag doesn't have anything to do with it. The issue is most likely the way you generate the preview content. Please make a [mcve] – something that replicates the problem.

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb right now. I just posted the answer to the question. Thanks all for taking the time trying to help, next time I will give a better example and try not to be as dumb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was that the pre-tag had nothing to do with it as the user "JJJ" pointed out.

> The pre tag doesn't have anything to do with it. The issue is most likely the way you generate the preview content. Please make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example – something that replicates the problem.

The problem was that I was telling Vue.js to render inside a `div` with the id #app. However the code section was not covered bu this `div`.

After moving the end-tag of the div to cover the codeblock with the `<pre></pre>` tags, all is working fine.

I feel so dumb right now, thanks for the help!